# UISegmentController added to a cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a tableView, and in that i have a UISegmentController. So each cell will have a UISegmentController each.

When the user clicks on a Segment in the UISegmentController (of a given cell), *how do  i know which cell was clicked*? and i need to NSLog the title of that cell, *how can i do this (note: the user will only be clicking on the UISegmentController of the cell*, and not the cell it self)

The following code is the method that will be called when the UISegmentController is clicked;

```
-(void)segmentOfCellPressed:(id)sender{

}
```

Comment: how do you add your SegmentController?

Comment: I have added the segmentcontroller to the cell. and the action is set like this `[segment addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentOfCellPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
-(void)segmentOfCellPressed:(id)sender{
    UISegmentController *segmentController = (UISegmentController *)sender;

    YourCellClass *cell=(YourCellClass *)segmentController.superview.superview;  // your clicked cell
 // or a little bit more verbose but imho easier to understand:
 // UIView *contentView = [segmentController superview];
 // YourCellClass *cell = (YourCellClass *)[contentView superview];

    NSIndexPath *path = [yourTableView indexPathForCell:cell]; //indexPath of clicked cell

}
```

Comment: depending on the actual cell layout you have to change the amount of superview. The answer works great if the segment is a direct subview of the contentView of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Should be pretty easy.  UISegmentedController derives from UIControl which derives UIView.  UIView objects have a tag property.  When you create each UISegmentedControler, give each one a unique tag value.  You will need to manage which tag values separately in a dictionary perhaps.

```
-(void)segmentOfCellPressed:(id)sender
{
   UISegmentedController *segmentedController = (UISegmentedController *)sender;
   UITableViewCell *cell = [self cellFromTag:segmentedController.tag];  
}
```

You will need to create a method called cellFromTag that will return the cell from the tag value of the UISegmentedController.  If you don't want the cell but something else, then you can return that instead.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing!

Comment: don't forget to think about a great algorithm to transform a indexPath consisting of rows and sections into a single number.

Comment: @Illep segmentedController.tag = tagValue.  Remember, each cell is reused so your segmentedController in each cell will also be reused.  You will need to update the segmentedController values and tag each time [tableView: cellforIndexPath:] is called.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the tag property of the segment controller to be the index of the cell in the cellForRowAtIndexPath then in the selector you could query the segment controller and then get the cell by the tag:

```
UISegmentController *segmentController = (UISegmentController*)sender;
int row = segmentController.tag;
```

Hopefully that helps.

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method where you add the UISegmentController to the cell do the following:

```
segment.tag = indexPath.row;
```